# How to add text labels to a bubble map plot in Python?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to build a bubble map plot using Python with text labels. I thought that there would be a simple way to do this without too much code.

So far, I have created the plot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpTbS.png) using scatter_mapbox() from Plotly Express.

Here is the code that you may use to create the same plot, by updating the `token` variable with your Mapbox access token:

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(CityName=['New York', 'Boston'], Latitude=[40.7128, 42.3601], Longitude=[-74.0060, -71.0589], Total=[100,200]))

token = 'PASTE YOUR TOKEN HERE'
px.set_mapbox_access_token(token)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat='Latitude', lon='Longitude', hover_name='CityName', size='Total')

plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

**Is there an easy way for me to modify the code so that I can have a "100" text label above the bubble for New York and a "200" text label above the bubble for Boston, to avoid forcing the user to hover over each bubble to obtain this information?**

I tried various things, such as:

- go.Scattermapbox(), which requires "import plotly.graph_objects as go"
- fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox())
- fig.update_layout()
- fig.add_annotation()

But I, personally, wasn't able to get any of them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add text to `px.scatter_mapbox()`. If given in string and list format, it will overlay the numbers on top of the markers. If you want to decorate that text, update the graph.

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(CityName=['New York', 'Boston'], Latitude=[40.7128, 42.3601], Longitude=[-74.0060, -71.0589], Total=[100,200]))

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open('mapbox_api_key.txt').read())

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lat='Latitude',
                        lon='Longitude',
                        hover_name='CityName',
                        size='Total',
                        text=[str(x) for x in df['Total']],
                        zoom=6
                       )

#plotly.offline.plot(fig)
fig.update_layout(height=500, font=dict(size=20, color='red'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Adding "size='Total', text=[str(x) for x in df['Total']]" worked for me. How do I format the string in dollars (i.e. $100, $200, $1,000, $2,000, etc.)? Also, is there any way to have the text above the bubble and centered horizontally?

Comment: To add a dollar sign, just combine it with the dollar sign. `['$'+ str(x) for x in df['Total']]` And I think the position of the string is always centered because the reference point is latitude and longitude. On the other hand, it would be difficult to align it to any other position.

Comment: Yes, that's the way that I format it too.

And ok, it's fine, there might be some way to hack it to be above the bubble, but if it's not easy to do or not possible, then this is good enough for sure.

Marked this as the answer.